# Pandas dataframe - create new column based on simple calcuation

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to make a calculation based on 4 columns in a dataframe and apply the result to a new column.

The 4 columns I'm interested in are as follows.

```
    rating_1, time_1, rating_2, time_2 col_x col_y etc
0   1              1         1       1     1     1
```

If time_1 is greater than time_2 I want rating_1 in the new column, if time_2 is greater I want rating_2 in the column.

What's the simplest way to do this please?

Comment: I should add i have multiple columns in my dataframe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use [numpy.where()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) method:

```
In [241]: x
Out[241]:
   rating_1  time_1  rating_2  time_2  col_x  col_y
0        11       1        21       1      1      1
1        12       2        21       1      1      1
2        13       1        21       5      1      1
3        14       5        21       5      1      1

In [242]: x['new'] = np.where(x.time_1 > x.time_2, x.rating_1, x.rating_2)

In [243]: x
Out[243]:
   rating_1  time_1  rating_2  time_2  col_x  col_y  new
0        11       1        21       1      1      1   21
1        12       2        21       1      1      1   12
2        13       1        21       5      1      1   21
3        14       5        21       5      1      1   21
```

Comment: Sorry to not be explicit and thanks for the pointer, but i need to do this for every row, not just one row.

Answer (score 1):

```
def myfunc(row):
   if row.time_1 >= row.time_2:
      return row.rating_1
   else:
      return row.rating_2
df.loc[:, 'calculatedColumn'] = df.apply(myfunc, axis = 1)
```